# Are gopter property tests safe for parallel use?

Tags: go, testing, parallel-testing, property-testing

I'm using [gopter](https://github.com/leanovate/gopter) for property testing and I'm interested in speeding up my test runs by running independent tests in parallel.

I can't find any reference in the documentation as to whether it's safe to call `t.Parallel()` in my test or not. Though, none of the examples that I've found are actually tests, they're all standalone console apps.

For example, here's one of my tests - is it safe to add the marked line?

```golang
func Test_NetworkSecurityGroup_WhenPropertiesConverted_RoundTripsWithoutLoss(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel() // Is this safe?
    parameters := gopter.DefaultTestParameters()
    parameters.MaxSize = 10
    properties := gopter.NewProperties(parameters)
    properties.Property(
        "Round trip from NetworkSecurityGroup to NetworkSecurityGroup via AssignPropertiesToNetworkSecurityGroup & AssignPropertiesFromNetworkSecurityGroup returns original",
        prop.ForAll(RunPropertyAssignmentTestForNetworkSecurityGroup, NetworkSecurityGroupGenerator()))
    properties.TestingRun(t, gopter.NewFormatedReporter(false, 240, os.Stdout))
}
```

I don't have any crashes when the `t.Parallel()` call is present, but I'm wary about proceeding without some reference that indicates it may be safe to do so.

Comment: The synopsis section in the readme says `No parallel commands ... yet?`, Not sure if it parallel safe. https://github.com/leanovate/gopter#synopsis

Comment: I couldn't decide whether that comment was specifically about commands (implying generators are safe for parallel use) or more general.